# Can a login item depend on the Core Foundation framework?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-foundation

For a project I'm making I want to make a login item that depends on the Core Foundation framework. The application is in essence a server that listens to incoming requests, and then hands those incoming requests off to another local application running on the system (that presents the user with a GUI). Is my architecture feasible or recommended?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A login item is just a program. You could make Pages a login item, and I'm pretty certain Pages depends upon the Core Foundation framework.

An alternative, and in my opinion superior, way of doing this is to use `launchd`.

Comment: Daemons using launchd can also use Core Foundation?

Comment: Core Foundation can be used anywhere except probably in a kernel extension.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go then. I'll accept your answer!